# Swift - return an element stored in a struct

Tags: swift, struct, uipickerview

**How can I retrieve an element that is stored in an array of struct?**
*I would like to show Alberta row when the view is loaded.*

On viewWillAppear:

selectedProvince = client?.province I get AB from a server/database. I want to show Alberta on the pickerview. Currently it shows AB.

Pickerview is shown when tap in a text field. So, AB is the value for this text field.

I use a pickerview to show the name and when selected I store the abbrev in a variable. After that, the data is saved.

When I load the view, I load the data. Province is stored as for exampple AB.

```
struct Province {
    let name, abbrev : String
}



let provinces = [Province(name: "Alberta", abbrev: "AB"), Province(name: "British Columbia", abbrev: "BC"),
                 Province(name: "Manitoba", abbrev: "MB"), Province(name: "New Brunswick", abbrev: "NB"),
                 Province(name: "Newfoundland and Labrador", abbrev: "NL"), Province(name: "Northwest Territorie", abbrev: "NT"),
                 Province(name: "Nova Scotia", abbrev: "NS"), Province(name: "Nunavut", abbrev: "NU"),
                 Province(name: "Ontario", abbrev: "ON"), Province(name: "Prince Edward Island", abbrev: "PE"),
                 Province(name: "Quebec", abbrev: "QC"), Province(name: "Saskatchewan", abbrev: "SK"),
                 Province(name: "Yukon", abbrev: "YT")]


var client: Client?
var selectedProvince: String?

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.title = "New"
    if (client?.client_id) != nil {
        self.title = "Edit"
        nameTextField.text = client?.name
        provinceTextField.text = client?.province
        cityTextField.text = client?.city
        addressTextField.text = client?.address
        postalCodeTextField.text = client?.postal_code
        selectedProvince = client?.province            
    }
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 50.0;

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(save))


    let thePicker = UIPickerView()
    provinceTextField.inputView = thePicker
    thePicker.delegate = self

    // ToolBar
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = .default
    toolBar.isTranslucent = true
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 92/255, green: 216/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    // Adding Button ToolBar
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ClientDetailViewController.doneClick))
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ClientDetailViewController.cancelClick))
    toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    provinceTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

}

@objc func doneClick() {
    provinceTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
@objc func cancelClick() {
    provinceTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}

// MARK: - Picker view
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return provinces.count
}

func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return provinces[row].name
}

func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    provinceTextField.text = provinces[row].name
    selectedProvince = provinces[row].abbrev
}
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You already seem to be doing what you are asking. Please [edit] your question and make it clear what issue you are having with the code you posted.

Comment: I edited it adding more info

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a strong reference to the picker view, a property on the top level:

```
var thePicker = UIPickerView()
```

and set up the parameters in `viewDidLoad`

```
provinceTextField.inputView = thePicker
thePicker.delegate = self
```

In `viewWillAppear` check if `selectedProvince` is not `nil` and get (safely) the index of the `Province` instance. Then set the corresponding row

```
selectedProvince = client?.province
if let province = selectedProvince, 
   let index = provinces.index(where: { $0.abbrev == province }) {
      thePicker.selectRow(index, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: Error ==> Cannot assign value of type 'Void' to type 'UIView?' on line: provinceTextField.inputView = thePicker.selectRow(index, inComponent: 0, animated: false)

Comment: It doesnt show the selected row on the pickerview when load the view. Im able to print the index on the console. it is correct.

Comment: I added a line after the code to select a row: provinceTextField.text = provinces[index].name ==> now, it shows the name on the text field and selected item in the pickerview.

Comment: Yes, that's because the picker is connected to the text field as input view.